# Comments disappearing on question

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

I commented earlier, on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1247553/ext4-on-flash-incompatibility). Now, the comment is gone, along with at least 3 other comments both by the question author and at least one other user.

The comments I remember, in order, were:

1. A very direct statement that it can’t be a backup if it isn’t redundant (or something along those lines)
2. Reply by question author, noting that’s not helping
3. My request for clarification (about unmounting)
4. Reply by question author, providing clarification

Granted, the clarification I requested was provided and the question updated. I’ve never seen comments being removed because of that though.

Why are all those comments gone now?

Comment: Are the comments considered "no longer needed" (one of the comment flag reason) for future readers?

Comment: Hm, could be. I don’t think they’re redundant though because they provide history. I also cannot easily follow up on the question anymore because my comment on it and all notifications are gone now.

Comment: If the question was updated, then the comments do not serve a purpose, and were likely flagged.  New information should be included in the question not in a comment.  Comments should be deleted if they themselves contain information that also exist in the question itself.  Our goal as reviewers should be that, there are no comments, and all information is supplied in the question itself.

Comment: But they do. The author even responded to me. All that is gone now. Had I not seen the notification soon enough, I would never have noticed. I very much disagree with this style of handling comments. Commenting on questions helps me track them. When those comments are deleted, I simply cannot do so in an efficient manner. IMHO, the Favorites feature wasn't made for that purpose either.

Comment: Comments shouldn't be used to have discussions, of a question doesn't contain information from a comment, that's a problem

Comment: ? I’m not talking about discussuions. I’m also not talking about a question not containing information present in comments.

Comment: @DanielB do you believe the comments should not be removed? Why?